# Using `useEffect()` inside of a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-ref

I have came across the following code in [FlyerChat](https://github.com/flyerhq/react-native-chat-ui).

```js
import * as React from 'react'

export const usePrevious = <T>(value: T) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<T>()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value
  }, [value])

  return ref.current
}
```

The function is called as

```
const previousChatMessages = usePrevious(chatMessages);
```

I have a hard time understanding how storing value in a `ref` in a function and with a `useEffect` is different than just keeping its value.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why, instead of using the value variable itself, we assign it to a ref in a useEffect and return that ref? How does this change the way this variable behaves?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is because library maintainers don't want to rerender when you change `chatMessages`

From React documentation:

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.

Comment: But if they don't assign the chatMessages to a state and just keep it as a variable, React won't re-render the page when its value changes. My question is what is the use of assigning it to a ref in another function, and updating that ref when chatMessages changes.

Comment: you can check PR with this custom hook https://github.com/flyerhq/react-native-chat-ui/commit/b52a819a2ff7958a718e8e5c08f86bcf4d5fc464 looks like they keep previous messages state in this ref